# SQL query with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-3.5

Please help the SQL Query in LINQ form - C#  .NET 3.5

```
select distinct location, country from Customer where   Customer_Code ='1001';
```

This is Query has no problem. Works fine in SQL. But getting error while i used the below LinQ query in ASP.NET code in LINQ format. Please help the same.

**EDIT**:

In ASP.NET code,

```
    var Query2 =  ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(p => p.Field<string>("Customer_Code") == "1001")
                 .Select(p => new {p.Field<string>("Location"),p.Field<string>("Country")});
```

ERROR:

**Error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.**

Kindly help!!!

Comment: Give an eg by stating some data and what is the result you expect?

Comment: In LINQ format how can I get the result for multiple values of distinct

Comment: Can you put some data as sample?

Comment: Provided code which i tried in VisualStudio IDE. Pls check!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
var query = dbContext.Customer
                     .Where(customer => customer.Customer_Code == "1001")
                     .Select(customer => new { customer.Location, customer.Country })
                     .Distinct();
```

The key here is the use of an anonymous type that serves as a tuple holding a customer's location and country.

---

**EDIT**: After your edit, it looks like you are using data-tables, not LINQ to SQL / Entities.
In which case, you probably want something like:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(p => p.Field<string>("Customer_Code") == "1001")
                 .Select(p => new 
                               {
                                  Location = p.Field<string>("Location"),
                                  Country = p.Field<string>("Country")
                               })
                 .Distinct();
```

Comment: Error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @sukumar: Please inspect the `Customer` type and check what the properties representing `Location` and `Country` are named as. Perhaps they are in lower case?

Comment: I checked....

Here the datatype which i provided is perfectly fine. 

i'm getting compile time error at the time of build itself not even at runtime or execution

Comment: With the resultant Query, I want to do some comparision with another datatable row. How i perform this??

Comment: @sukumar: That isn't all that clear; I suggest posting another question.

Comment: My Question is After getting the result of a Query in the above i want to loop through....Can i Loop through the same???

Comment: `foreach(var a in query)Console.WriteLine(a.Location + " " + a.Country);`